# How to print std::map<int, std::vector<int>>?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, stdvector, stdmap

Following is my code for creating a `map<int, vector<int>>` and printing:

```
//map<int, vector>
map<int, vector<int>> int_vector;
vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(2);
vec.push_back(5);
vec.push_back(7);

int_vector.insert(make_pair(1, vec));

vec.clear();
if (!vec.empty())
{
    cout << "error:";
    return -1;
}
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(3);
vec.push_back(6);
int_vector.insert(make_pair(2, vec));

//print the map
map<int, vector<int>>::iterator itr;
cout << "\n The map int_vector is: \n";
for (itr2 = int_vector.begin(); itr != int_vector.end(); ++itr)
{
    cout << "\t " << itr->first << "\t" << itr->second << "\n";
}
cout << endl;
```

The printing part does not work because of the

```
error: C2678: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 
'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Note that you can simplify your code, with `vector<int> vec{2, 5, 7};` or even `std::map<int, vector<int>> int_vector{{1, {2, 5, 7}}, {2, {1, 3, 6}}};`. and for range: `for (const auto& p : int_vector) {std::cout << p.first; print_vector(p.second);}`.

Comment: You already worked out that you have to implement this yourself for the map; curious why you thought it would work for the vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of your maps(`std::map<int, std::vector<int>>`) is a *vector of `int`* s and there is no `operator<<` defined for printing a `std::vector<int>` in the standard. You need to iterate through the vector(i.e. values of the map) to print the elements.

```
for (itr = int_vector.begin(); itr != int_vector.end(); ++itr)
//     ^^ --> also you had a typo here: itr not itr2     
{
    cout << "\t " << itr->first << "\t";
    for(const auto element: itr->second) std::cout << element << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

That being said, if you have access to C++11, you could use *[range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)*. And in C++17, you could do more intuitively *[structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)* declarations for the *key-value* of the map:

```
for (auto const& [key, Vec] : int_vector)
{
    std::cout << "\t " << key << "\t";                         // print key
    for (const auto element : Vec) std::cout << element << " ";// print value
    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

---

**Remark**: As *@Jarod42* pointed out in the comments, the given code could be simplified if the entries are known beforehand.

for example with [`std::map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)ing:

```
using ValueType = std::vector<int>;
std::map<int, ValueType> int_vector;
int_vector.emplace(1, ValueType{ 2, 5, 7 });
int_vector.emplace(2, ValueType{ 1, 3, 6 });
```

or simply initialize the map using the *[`std::initializer_list` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map)* of the `std::map`.

```
const std::map<int, std::vector<int>> int_vector { {1, {2, 5, 7}}, {2, {1, 3, 6}} };
```

Comment: `/*const*/ std::map<int, std::vector<int>> int_vector` Why `/*const*/`?

Comment: Sorry, absolutely right. I read `int_vector` as a function definition for some reason. Uncomment the `const`!

Answer (score 2):

*error: C2678: binary '<<': no operator found*

Also means you can write your own operator. Doing so can be handy as your objects become more complicated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using vector_int_type = std::vector<int>;

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const vector_int_type& vect) {
    for (const auto& i : vect)
        os << '\t' << i;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, vector_int_type> int_map;
    int_map[1] = vector_int_type{ 1,2,3 };
    int_map[2] = vector_int_type{ 4,5,6 };

    for (auto& item : int_map)
        std::cout << item.first << " is: " << item.second << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To print
map<int, vector<'int'> > mp;

```
 for(auto it: mp){
     cout<<it.first<<" ";
     for(auto i : it.second){
         cout<<i<<" ";
     }
     cout<<endl;
  }
```

Comment: This answer will make a copy of every vector in the map (Avoid with for '(auto & : mp)'), and there is no description about why it is made like that.